# Why is there an additional annotation (@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable) in newer versions of Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After upgrading from Android Studio version 4.1.3 to 4.2.1, I noticed an additional annotation is added where there's @Nullable annotation.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

It seems redundant to me. What's the purpose of this additional annotation and is it really necessary to use it?